# Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC Q1 2010: Not compiling: Shows warning :The referenced component 'System.Web.MVC' could not be found

Tags: asp.net, telerik, compilation, compiler-errors

If I try to compile the source of Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC Q1 2010 it is not getting compiled. It shows error:

> The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does
>   not exist in the namespace
>   'System.Web' (are you missing an
>   assembly reference?)

Tried to remove and add the `System.Web.MVC` but still it dont recognize it as valid reference and dont include in the compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Buid/Debug configuration to Release MVC2/Net35 OR Debug MVC2/Net35

It will compile.